# Dynamically load <meta> properties only for one JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page where I instigate an JS application in a Jquery dialog. How can I load the meta properties:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scalable=0">
```

dynamically to be only applied for the JS file.

After some research this just might be what I'm looking for:
http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/

Answer (score 1):

Meta tags are only applied in the document ( in the `<head>` element ), not individual files.

If you need that meta for a dialog, I guess the only solution available would be to load an `<iFrame>` that includes the meta tags in its `<head>` element.

Comment: Is there any chance to load those preoperties any other way?

Comment: not to my knowledge, perhaps someone else can provide an alternative